# How to make ui-grid responsive to browser resize event in Angular typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, less

I am coding Angular 1.x in typescript 1.5 + less css + bootstrap. 
ui-grid is used as an attribute on div as

Template

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" 
     class="ui-grid-collapsible" 
     ui-grid-auto-resize >
</div>
```

The view controller is setting `gridOption` in `$scope`

```
 this.$scope.gridOptions = {
                enableSorting: true,
                headerTemplate: "path to header template",
                rowTemplate: "path to row template"
                enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
                enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
                columnDefs: []
                ......
}
```

Any pointers on why grid is not resizing on browser resize when other components on controller view are resizing.

Please assist. Do I need to catch the browser resize event and set chart grid height and width accordingly? If yes, then how?

Comment: How about clean up your question so the HTML you are asking for help with is valid. You are missing a couple `<`s and your `ui-grid-auto-resize` class is outside the quotes. It's nearly impossible to tell what you issue might be with what you have provided. Also, `this.$scope...`, is that even valid?

Comment: this is the controller instance and $scope is the private instance of it which I am setting in  controller constructor and initializing it with injected $scope.  The Grid is loading with data coming from real service.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ui-grid tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing) you need to

> include the 'ui.grid.autoResize' module in your angular app's dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but unfortunately that directive i have tried with no luck and it has slighly different purpose. If you try to resize the window of ui-grid tutorial link you have shared, even the tutorial Grid is unresponsive to browser resizing

Comment: Just adding to above. My new approach till now. I have written a custom directive with   restrict: "A". In the link phase i am binding angular element  $window resize event. After checking browser innerheight and innerwidth, applying a css property on element.  I am using my code along with attribute 'ui-grid-auto-resize' from ui-grid

Comment: Does anyone know if this causes a `$digest` every 250 ms it checks?

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap so you can use:

Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
   <table class='table'>
   ........
   ........
   ........
   </table>
</div>
```

See [Responsive tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Other way is to write the JavaScript to convert the table structure into two columns Label: Value, which is not so easy.

Comment: ui-grid is it's own table component. I don't think the OP wants a bootstrap grid

Comment: I have constraint to use ui-grid library